# AWS Android Project Sign on

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I just tried AWS for the first time to build a basic hello world android app with user authentication and I seem to be missing something critical. I worked with Android apps before so I have all the software setup there plus AWS CLI installed I created an android project in AWS Mobile Hub, created user pool, I configured signon/register add on in my new AWS project and I clicked on Integrate button but I'm not sure what's next. I saw on youtube some people had build and test buttons that they used to generate Android Studio project on a menu on the left, I'm not seeing any of that, how can I build a skeleton project in AWS to download so I can finalize it with Android Studio? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link which teach you step by step on how to build a skeleton project in AWS  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-android-notes-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/analytics.md.